# Unity Vuforia dosen't show 3d model in android but works in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, vuforia

Hi I am newbie to Ar development.I am working on a very simple project where the 3d cube model is shown on the image target.When i run the project in unity,it works fine by showing the cube on the image,but when i build it for android and run on my mobile,the camera opens up but the cube does not get shown on the image target.I have added the license key in the vuforia configuration and wanted to know if i am doing anything wrong.

Unity Engine - 2020.3.48f1
Vuforia version - 10.16

My Project setup

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My Console warnings when i try to build
**
[image]

**Also when it is building,i get the warning as below
**
[image]

My output when i run in unity

[image]

I have tried changing the unity version to 2019,but the same thing happens.I have also tried to playaround player settings like changing the color space from linear to gamma ,changing the target architecture from ARMv7 to ARM64, but nothing seems to work.I am stuck on this from 2 days and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update Unity? As it is shown here Vuforia Engine requires Unity 2021.3 or newer https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/supported-versions

Comment: Yes emay,tried also but still same issue